# What is the point in specifying different platforms in FROM clause of the Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have encountered the following `FROM` clause in a Dockerfile:
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 arm64v8/amazoncorretto:18`

According to Docker reference:

> The optional --platform flag can be used to specify the platform of the image in case FROM references a multi-platform image

Can someone explain, what is the difference between specifying the platform in the `--platform` option vs in the image name (`arm64v8/amazoncorretto:18`), and why would someone have different platforms specified there?

Comment: For that image, it has no value.

Comment: image name is just a group name, it does not affect anything. You can have `anything/anything` it is just some name of the user in docker hub https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multi-platform images, the `docker build` will select the platform matching the build host. If you want to select a different platform from a multi-platform image, you use the `--platform` option on the FROM step. This is useful for building images to run on different hosts than the build host (e.g. building on an M1/ARM laptop but running on an AMD64 server). This requires emulation (qemu/binfmt_misc) to handle any RUN steps since the binaries in the filesystem will be designed for a different CPU architecture.

For the image you have listed, it's only available for a single platform, so the `--platform` option makes no sense:

```bash
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect arm64v8/amazoncorretto:18
Name:      docker.io/arm64v8/amazoncorretto:18
MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
Digest:    sha256:37f6b76c24b03ab5c93bbb1af157a6b15a45fbfe6c9be1585c47c035810de19c
```

Comment: So is there any difference between `FROM --platform=linux/arm64 amazoncorretto` and `FROM arm64v8/amazoncorretto`? (let's consider that `amazoncoretto` is a multi-arch image)

Comment: If the image is multi-arch, and your build platform does not match the requested platform, then yes, it would be a different image being used.